# I am completely new to Cardano eco system. To learn it from the absolute basic, where do I start?

Tags: ada, decentralized-applications, smart-contract, learning

This is a broad question but I am sure many might have this in their mind.
I am an upcoming blockchain engineer and my exposure to Cardano eco system is limited to buying the ADA cryptocurrency and watching Charles's vlogs. But I want to professionally start using Cardano as my blockchain of choice, for building applications on top of it. For that, I want to learn how to create smart contracts and dApps using this network. I couldn't find any tutorials on sites like Udemy for this but there were many a plenty for Ethereum.
Can someone suggest a learning path to learn to build dApps? Any tutorials that I can follow?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a lot of places/tools to start, so, here are some of them sorted in a learning path:

1. [Developers guide](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/), this has a complete guide of tools to start developing on cardano. You can find them in the *Builder Tools* section.
2. **Plutus**, the smart contracts language (based on Haskell) used in Cardano: [Plutus pioneer program](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program)

   - **[Haskell and Cryptocurrencies](https://github.com/iohkedu/haskell-2020)** by IOHK, recently published on Github.
   - Haskell, you need to understand the basics: [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters)
3. **cardano-node** and **cardano-cli**, last one is a command line tool to interact with Cardano: [Installing the Cardano node](https://docs.cardano.org/getting-started/installing-the-cardano-node) (just note there are executable nodes)

   - Learn some basic commands from [Cardano Node CLI Reference](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/cardano-node-cli-reference.md/)
4. [Minting NFTs](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting-nfts) (as native assets without plutus) there is a good tutorial in the developers guide
5. [Alonzo testnet program](https://github.com/input-output-hk/Alonzo-testnet) has a set of exercises to write and submit Plutus scripts on the Alonzo testnets using the node CLI. Also to create DApps.
6. There are more tools to use on your DApps:

   1. [Blockfrost](https://blockfrost.io/) is a gateway to the Cardano ecosystem as an API
   2. [Nami Wallet](https://github.com/Berry-Pool/nami-wallet) is a browser based wallet extension to interact with the Cardano blockchain
   3. [PAB (Plutus Application Backend)](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/releases/tag/v2021-11-05) provides the components and environment to help developers interact with smart contracts. [Beta release](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/releases/tag/v2021-11-05) to use on testnet.
   4. [Cardano Wallet](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet) provides an HTTP Application Programming Interface (API) and command-line interface (CLI) for working with your wallet.

I know it's a lot of information, but you can go step by step. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @georgeos !

Answer (score 2):

Start learning [Plutus Pioneer Program](https://plutus-pioneer-program.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).