# Is there an established pathway yet for someone with a purely mathematical background to become a fully equipped Cardano developer? If so, what is it?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, blockchain, development, learning, plutus-starter

Title asks my question. I have a mathematics degree (undergrad) and have dipped a toe in the water of software development in Python, but have no clue where the optimal place to start to become an effective Cardano developer would be. Presumably someone here has walked the path I’m hoping to set out on towards building on Cardano, I’d love some advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome, Brody Alden. I feel math and Cardano goes hand in hand. Most of the core team including the founder is a mathematician. However, this is an opinion-based question and it is best suited in the Cardano forum at https://forum.cardano.org/ . Hoping to see you often with technical questions on Cardano here.

Comment: You can start learning Haskell which will help you in Math too. Then you can migrate to smart contract development with Plutus. haskell.mooc.fi/ is one of the site for starting Haskell. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igV7kMXcdpw is the best material to start learning Haskell.

Comment: Take a look on this: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4444/i-am-completely-new-to-cardano-eco-system-to-learn-it-from-the-absolute-basic

Comment: I would suggest reading the book Mastering Bitcoin (https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook) and then following the videos of the Plutus Pioneer Program (https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLK8ah7DzglhgV7W6BHcoIzRArjzs_UuSY).