# How do I learn Plutus

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I am having a hard time learning plutus the all of the plutus pioneer code doesn't work anymore due to rapid expansion of the plutus librarys. What other paths are out there for me to learn this skill in a more relevant state?

Comment: Take a look on this: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4444/i-am-completely-new-to-cardano-eco-system-to-learn-it-from-the-absolute-basic

Answer (score 2):

You can start learning from here

https://github.com/iohkedu/haskell-2020

the course is an introduction to Haskell and Block-Chain.

Also try to first learn Haskell as well as how to use Cabal, I highly recommend to learn all these tools before jumping into Plutus.

Answer (score 1):

> all of the plutus pioneer code doesn't work anymore

For each week, you can look at the SHA for the version of Plutus they are using. You can check out that version of Plutus (via git) before running `nix-shell` (you probably can't use the Dev Docker image for the PPP homework).

Other than that, I'd recommend three things:

1. Go through all the Plutus Pioneer Program lectures and homework. You don't need to understand everything the first time, but get comfortable reading the code and general concepts.
2. Give yourself additional challenges that are simple enough to stay engaged. It's easy to bite off too much. Variations on the PPP code is a great place to start.
3. Try to answer questions here on the StackExchange that you want to understand. Every bit helps, especially since the community is still young.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn Plutus you must have a solid understanding of Haskell, the resource that Alicia pointed is really a good starting point. Very likely in Q1 2022, there will be another iteration of the Plutus Pioneer program which will be taught using the PAB (set a reminder for this, [here](https://testnets.cardano.org/en/plutus-pioneer-program/) ). Now, if you really can't wait, go over the iteration #2 on YouTube and make sure to  cabal build Plutus with the tag that was working about 4 months ago, you can have a look at Gimbalabs, to [get around this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbTOZWr1-yM).