# Starting to learn development on Cardano blockchain platform

Tags: decentralized-applications, development

I am Wim.

I want to develop dapps on the Cardano blockchain platform.

I have a little bit of programming experience in Java.
So i think i will start from scratch to learn Cardano and the development in its platform.

What is the best place to start to learn the whole chain (Cardano ecosystem to development of dapps with Cardano?

Is there an IDE for installing on a Windows PC that have all the features and the Haskall platform  to start learning?

So where do i start the learning path?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help you? https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/4446/1231

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of IDE I think VS Code is used a lot https://code.visualstudio.com For example in the Starter Project see https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter You will soon learn that Haskell and pure functional programming is the approach with Cardano and Plutus so I recommend that you spend some time every day on Haskell.
Here is intro to Haskell for Plutus and again Visual Studio code is used.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5b-YG558ft8
the developer portal also recommends http://learnyouahaskell.com

Answer (score 1):

Start with the [Cardano Developer Portal](https://developers.cardano.org/)

It has enough hyperlinks to keep you occupied for a while :)